# Создание кастомных полей в админке Django

Tags: python, django

Насколько я знаю, кроме полей, которые непосредственно присутствуют в модели, в админку модели можно добавить и свои поля, оформив их в виде методов класса, наследуемого от ModelAdmin. Но у меня происходит ошибка.

```py
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        ('Основная информация', {
            'fields': ('order_number',),
        }),

    )

    #Кастомное поле
    def order_number(self, obj):
        return obj.id
    order_number.short_description = 'Номер заказа'
```

Происходит вот такая ошибка:

> Unknown field(s) (order_number) specified for Order. Check
>   fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class OrderAdmin.

Comment: Непонятно, что нужно

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `readonly_fields = ('order_number',)`. И еще у вас два нижних подчеркивания в `order__number.short_description`

Comment: @Andrey с двойным подчеркиванием - опечатка. А `readonly_fields` помогло. Спасибо! Вообще это логично, я просто не подумал.

Comment: @Andrey оформите как ответ, пожалуйста

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров оформил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Методы модели и класса `ModelAdmin` можно отображать в админке, добавив их в список/кортеж `readonly_fields` ([документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields)).

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('order_number',)
    fieldsets = (
        ('Основная информация', {
            'fields': ('order_number',),
        }),

    )

    #Кастомное поле
    def order_number(self, obj):
        return obj.id
    order_number.short_description = 'Номер заказа'
```